# double slashes in scheme rather than tripple

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo, deep-linking

App was opening fine with `myapp://` scheme. Suddenly it stopped opening with `myapp://` scheme. I called `Linking.makeUrl()` and it returned `myapp:///`. Now when i open `myapp:///` scheme the app works fine. I can't seem to find any place where this change happened. I want to use double slashes in my deeplink. It's an Expo App and the only configuration i can find for deeplink is setting the scheme in `app.json` file like `"scheme": "myapp"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the [answer](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/10012#issuecomment-683962453) from expo community. This is the new behavior of Expo deeplink after SDK 37 update. The answer was as follows:-

> we changed this in SDK 37. [You can read more about that here](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/6497#issuecomment-574882448), or in
> the changelogs for SDK 37. To summarize:
>
> Custom URIs with only 2 slashes aren't valid URIs, usually it consists
> of :///[/...]. In these custom URIs, we
> don't have a host and must leave that blank in order to comply with
> [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3).